# WIF/AD FS, timeout after idle

Tags: jquery, ajax, wif, adfs

I got an application which uses WIF and ADFS for authentication. This application is in Javascript/jQuery, and uses $.ajax calls to connect to an MVC Web Api.

Here is my issue, if the application goes idle for too long (30ish minutes), any subsequent call to the MVC Web API returns a 302 found code, which probably redirects to my ADFS authentication page.

However I do not know how to deal with the 302 Found message in an Ajax call. Is there any way for me to elegantly handle this call, then re-do my original Web API call?

Thank you.

Comment: What authentication have you got on your WEB API methods? You should probably check the HTTP status code returned from the AJAX/WEB API call  and redirect the entire page to the login.

Comment: The authentication is done by an ADFS login page. However I don't have to re-type the username and password manually

Comment: If you don't require a retype, can you simply extend the expiration (as well as redirect the page if a 302 does occur)?

Comment: How do I extend the expiration with AD FS?

Answer (score 1):

We have a helper for this in Thinktecture IentityModel: http://brockallen.com/2013/02/19/suppress-login-redirects-for-api-clients-in-wif-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/

Comment: Looks interesting. However if I disable the login redirect for Web API calls, what will happen when my application is idle for too long and I try doing a Web API call? Will the call go through, or will an exception be thrown?

Comment: That's up to your authorization. This helpers simply prevents the 302 when it's an API call.

Comment: I finally got around to using the helper, but it didn't change anything, I still get a 302 Found from my WebAPI calls, which my Ajax calls cannot handle